# How to rearrange element in an array diagonally

Tags: python, arrays, diagonal

Very new to using Python but I have managed to come up with a code that gives me the array below. Won't go into the details of the assignment but the next step I would want to rearrange the -6 element so that it is placed diagonally.

```
[[-6.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
[-6.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
[-6.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
[-6.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
[-6.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
[-6.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
[-6.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
[-6.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

Comment: Give an example of expected input along with expected output and the code you have so far to solve this problem.

Comment: I've tried using the np.argmin function with a code like this: b=a[:,np.argmin(a,axis=1)].

Comment: What is the exact transformation you are looking for? Please try to explain in precise mathematical terms.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the diagonal is easy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,10,(11,10)) # I notice your matrix is not square!

In [31] a
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 7, 6, 0, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 9],
       [4, 7, 6, 0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 2],
       [2, 3, 9, 6, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 7],
       [5, 9, 6, 8, 3, 3, 0, 8, 3, 5],
       [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 8, 2, 4, 8, 7],
       [3, 3, 1, 6, 6, 4, 9, 5, 1, 2],
       [8, 1, 8, 4, 9, 6, 6, 4, 2, 7],
       [0, 8, 0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 7, 7, 1],
       [9, 2, 6, 2, 8, 9, 4, 8, 0, 8],
       [4, 4, 2, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 8, 6],
       [5, 3, 5, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 5, 7]])




np.fill_diagonal(a,a[:,0])

In [33] a
Out[33]: 
array([[0, 7, 6, 0, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 9],
       [4, 4, 6, 0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 2],
       [2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 7],
       [5, 9, 6, 5, 3, 3, 0, 8, 3, 5],
       [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 2, 4, 8, 7],
       [3, 3, 1, 6, 6, 3, 9, 5, 1, 2],
       [8, 1, 8, 4, 9, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7],
       [0, 8, 0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 0, 7, 1],
       [9, 2, 6, 2, 8, 9, 4, 8, 9, 8],
       [4, 4, 2, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 8, 4],
       [5, 3, 5, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 5, 7]])
```

However, if you are wanted to do a transformation/rotation then you must determine how you want that to happen (I don't see how you will work that on a non-square matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you're trying to get the values into a diagonal formation, so you're going to be placing the next -6 one place further to the right than the previous one. Since you're going to be indexing something by one every time, this sounds like a good place for a loop.